# Rails 4. No route matches, missing required keys: [:id] when submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have Comment, User and Product models. The user can leave a comment in the Product's show view.

So, I tried to implement the commenting functionality, but when I submit the form with the comment, I get the following error:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /comments
>
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products", :id=>nil} missing required
>   keys: [:id]

The `comments` table in db looks like this:

```
id         :integer          not null, primary key
body       :text
created_at :datetime         not null
updated_at :datetime         not null
user_id    :integer
product_id :integer
```

Here' my `views/comments/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>
      <%= f.input :body, required: true, placeholder: 'Type in a new comment...', input_html: { class: 'form-control'}, label: false %>
      <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block' %>
<% end %>
```

My `CommentsController.rb`:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    # @comment = Comment.new(user: current_user, product: params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          redirect_to product_path(@comment.product_id), notice: 'Comment Created!'
        end
      end
    else
      redirect_to product_path(@comment.product_id), notice: 'Something went wrong'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @comment.update(comment_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          redirect_to product_path(@comment.product_id), notice: 'Comment Updated'
        end
      end
    else
      redirect_to comment_path(@comment_id), notice: 'Something went wrong'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy!
    respond_to do
      redirect_to product_path(@comment.product_id), notice: 'Comment Deleted'
    end
  end

  private

  def set_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

The error is thrown at line 15 in the `create` method in `else` condition: `redirect_to product_path(@comment.product_id), notice: 'Something went wrong'`, which means that not only it is giving me the `no routes matches` error, but it also doesn't save the comment.

In my `views/products/show.html.erb` there's this line:

`<%= render 'comments/form' %>`

And in my `ProductsController.rb` I have this:

```
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comments = Comment.where(product_id: product.id).order('created_at DESC')
  end
```

In my routes file I have this:

```
resources :products, only: [:show]
resources :comments, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

I've been trying to figure out how to resolve that issue, but didn't succeed. Could you please help me with that?